# EFCache CachingProviderServices lacks static Instance property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am attempting to use the EFCache NuGet package (https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache) in a .NET 4.5 project, and running into this error on startup:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=The Entity Framework provider type '
EFCache.CachingProviderServices, EFCache, Version=1.1.3.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=46c4868af4307d2c' did not have a static 
property or field named 'Instance'. Entity Framework providers must 
declare a static property or field named 'Instance' that returns the 
singleton instance of the provider.
```

EFCache.CachingProviderServices extends System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices, which does NOT have a static Instance property. So it seems that this property is not necessarily there in all cases.

Looking at the the code of EFCache.CachingProviderServices, I don't see any sensible way for it to have a static instance property, since its purpose is to serve as a wrapper around another DBProviderServices instance that is passed as a constructor argument.

Does anyone who's gotten EFCache to work with Entity Framework have any thoughts on what's going on?

EFCache version is 1.1.3.0. I've seen the same issue using Entity Framework 6.1.0 and 6.2.0.  Web.config section looks like this:

```
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="EFCache.CachingProviderServices, EFCache" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the following line in the config file:

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="EFCache.CachingProviderServices, EFCache" />
```

It's supposed to describe the actual db provider and for MySQL it usually looks like this:

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
```

In general, as described in the linked page, `EFCache.CachingProviderServices` is a *wrapping* provider, hence it's not supposed to (and can't) be registered as a regular database provider (which requires them to provide the static `Instance` property/field mentioned in the exception).

Instead, it has to be activated via custom `DbConfiguration` or static `EntityFrameworkCache.Initialize()` method as explained in [How to use it](https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache#how-to-use-it).

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be a crucial piece of the problem.  Another part was that I was getting an error in the parsing of the configuration string, about 'Invalid key "port"'.  This was traced to the fact that my class implementing   DbConfiguration needs to also point specifically to MySql components.